# React Integration: How to connect react components with rails backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, integration

Apologies if there is a simple answer to this, but I'm very new to react.

I'm building an application in react and I'm trying to integrate two basic forms (register/login) with a rails backend. I don't really need to authenticate the user at this point, I just need it to remember the user and create a session.

Is there an easy way to do this that avoids using something like Devise? If somebody could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

As I mentioned the forms will be very basic. Something like this:

```
    <form>
       <label for='email'>Email Address:</label>
       <input type="text" name="email" />
       <label for='password'>Password:</label>
       <input type="text" name="email" />
       <button> Login</button>
    </form>
```

and

```
       <form>
          <label for='email'>First Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="first-name" />
          <label for='password'>Last Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="last-name" />
          <label for='email'>Email Address:</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" />
          <label for='password'>Password:</label>
          <input type="text" name="password" />
          <label for='password'>Confirm Password:</label>
          <input type="text" name="password" />
          <button> Register</button>

        </form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a separate Rails App and React App you might want to create a Rails API instead and access the API from your React frontend. You can see an example here: https://medium.com/@bruno_boehm/reactjs-ruby-on-rails-api-heroku-app-2645c93f0814

Comment: Sounds like you want a `session` variable https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session

Comment: Rails is an MVC framework it means it handles the view part. If you are going to use React I suggest you using just the server-side of the Ruby language. Otherwise, take a look at https://medium.com/wineofbits/my-first-ruby-on-rails-react-app-in-just-15-minutes-51d73f0de3c6

Answer (score 0):

First, your rails backend need to be a rest API, if already is, you need to make the request of your react app, I recommend you to use Axios

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Rest Api on your Rails backend. Once you have your API endpoints you can make calls from react on those endpoints using fetch or axios whichever u like.